# Xcode 4.5 and ios 6 sdk orientation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator, ios6, kobold2d

I know that this topic has had many threads started but none of them give a fix for the problem. I have been creating a game with kobold2d which is using cocos2d v1.1.0-beta2b and ever since I upgraded to xcode 4.5 and ios 6 then all of the orientation has been thrown off. Normally the cocos2d apps will start up in landscape mode but now with the updates it starts up in portrait mode and causes all of the objects on the layer to be reversed, but somehow this has fixed itself. So now my project starts up in landscape mode on both the simulator and the ios device but all of the content on the screen is still in portrait mode. Everything was working just fine before I updated to the latest software. What can I do to fix this?

So I decided to build my project with the older xcode 4.4.1 and see how the output in the console differed from the new xcode 4.5 and this what I was finding:

Output for xcode 4.5

```
2012-09-21 14:50:54.558 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: OS version: 6.0 (0x06000000)
2012-09-21 14:50:54.560 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Computer, Inc.
2012-09-21 14:50:54.560 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
2012-09-21 14:50:54.560 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 APPLE
2012-09-21 14:50:54.561 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
2012-09-21 14:50:54.561 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH: 16
2012-09-21 14:50:54.562 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2012-09-21 14:50:54.562 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2012-09-21 14:50:54.563 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2012-09-21 14:50:54.563 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2012-09-21 14:50:54.563 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2012-09-21 14:50:54.564 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: compiled with NPOT support: NO
2012-09-21 14:50:54.564 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: compiled with VBO support in TextureAtlas : YES
2012-09-21 14:50:54.564 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: compiled with Affine Matrix transformation in CCNode : YES
2012-09-21 14:50:54.565 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
2012-09-21 14:50:54.565 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCDirector init] : cocos2d: cocos2d v1.1.0-beta2b
2012-09-21 14:50:54.566 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCDirector init] : cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
2012-09-21 14:50:54.566 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[KKAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] : Kobold2D™ v1.1.2
2012-09-21 14:50:54.571 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] Retina Display enabled: YES
2012-09-21 14:50:54.573 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[ES1Renderer resizeFromLayer:] : cocos2d: surface size: 480x320
2012-09-21 14:50:54.579 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[AppDelegate initializationComplete] : ARC is either not available or not enabled
2012-09-21 14:50:54.609 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCDirectorDisplayLink startAnimation] : startAnimation
2012-09-21 14:50:54.610 KTireHoops-iOS[4539:c07] -[CCDirectorDisplayLink startAnimation] : cocos2d: Frame interval: 1
```

Output for xcode 4.4.1

```
2012-09-21 14:52:01.343 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: OS version: 5.1 (0x05010000)
2012-09-21 14:52:01.345 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:   Apple Computer, Inc.
2012-09-21 14:52:01.345 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL_RENDERER: Apple Software Renderer
2012-09-21 14:52:01.346 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL_VERSION:  OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 APPLE
2012-09-21 14:52:01.346 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
2012-09-21 14:52:01.347 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL_MAX_MODELVIEW_STACK_DEPTH: 16
2012-09-21 14:52:01.347 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL_MAX_SAMPLES: 4
2012-09-21 14:52:01.347 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
2012-09-21 14:52:01.348 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: YES
2012-09-21 14:52:01.348 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
2012-09-21 14:52:01.350 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
2012-09-21 14:52:01.350 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: compiled with NPOT support: NO
2012-09-21 14:52:01.351 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: compiled with VBO support in TextureAtlas : YES
2012-09-21 14:52:01.351 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: compiled with Affine Matrix transformation in CCNode : YES
2012-09-21 14:52:01.351 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCConfiguration init] : cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
2012-09-21 14:52:01.352 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCDirector init] : cocos2d: cocos2d v1.1.0-beta2b
2012-09-21 14:52:01.352 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCDirector init] : cocos2d: Using Director Type:CCDirectorDisplayLink
2012-09-21 14:52:01.353 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[KKAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] : Kobold2D™ v1.1.2
2012-09-21 14:52:01.360 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] Retina Display enabled: YES
2012-09-21 14:52:01.361 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[KKRootViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] : shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
2012-09-21 14:52:01.361 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[KKRootViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] : shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
2012-09-21 14:52:01.362 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[KKRootViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] : shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
2012-09-21 14:52:01.362 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[KKRootViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] : shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
2012-09-21 14:52:01.362 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[KKRootViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] : shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
2012-09-21 14:52:01.363 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[KKRootViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] : shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
2012-09-21 14:52:01.396 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[AppDelegate initializationComplete] : ARC is either not available or not enabled
2012-09-21 14:52:01.436 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCDirectorDisplayLink startAnimation] : startAnimation
2012-09-21 14:52:01.437 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[CCDirectorDisplayLink startAnimation] : cocos2d: Frame interval: 1
2012-09-21 14:52:01.438 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[KKRootViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:] : shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation
2012-09-21 14:52:01.439 KTireHoops-iOS[5207:c07] -[ES1Renderer resizeFromLayer:] : cocos2d: surface size: 320x480
```

From what I can see the (shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation) method is not getting called anymore in the new xcode with ios 6. Which is causing the weird orientation bug. Does anyone know of a fix for this.

Comment: This is a known issue and you could search in cocos2d forum.

Comment: here is a hot fix http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/73

Answer (score 12):

Here is the quick fix:

- In ***AppDelegate.mm*** file ***replace***  the line

  ```
  [window_ addSubview:navController_.view];
  ```

  with

  ```
  if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 6.0){
      [window_ setRootViewController:navController_];
  }
  else{
      [window_ addSubview:navController_.view];
  }
  ```
- ***Add*** the following method in the ***AppDelegate.mm***

  ```
  - (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because Apple Has changed the Way of managing the Orientation of UIViewController. In Ios6 Oreintation handles Differently .in iOS6 containers (such as UINavigationController) do not consult their children to determine whether they should autorotate. By default, an app and a view controller’s supported interface orientations are set to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for the iPad idiom and UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown for the iPhone idiom.So device getting orientation changed by default.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/33326

[EDIT] the above link does not work anymore.
The reason could be cocos2d-iphone group had fixed this bug or something else.

For those who still have the same problem, a better way could be google

`cocos2d iphone ios6 orientation bug`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for pointing out that. coz I didn't know much about objective-c, I probably not able to provide more detailed answers, just hope this link could help the asker. I will try to avoid link-only answer next time. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, just worth being aware that such posts get flagged by the moderator tools. Even just some useful link text that says what it's about can help.